# Автоматизация массовой установки приложений на Android 5.1

Tags: android

Есть мно-ооого новых планшетов Huawei 2, на которых нужно включить отладку по USB и поставить набор приложений. Можно ли это как-то автоматизировать?

Нашёл только приложение [APK Batch Installer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1531880), но оно не совсем о том.

Answer (score 1):

Можете установить `ADB`, и выполнить для каждого APK-файла такую команду:

```
adb install <путь к APK-файлу>
```